# sqlalchemy show results for query in jinja for html page

Tags: html, sqlalchemy, jinja2

Currenlty trying to display a number to a html dashboard that the user imputted in their login form, however I am unsure if my sql query or use of jinja is preventing this from occuring. At the moment, there is a blank space in the dashboard where the number is supposed to be displayed.
html:

```
{% block main %}
{% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    {{ message }}
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
{% endfor %}
<div class="grid-container">
    <header class="header">
        <div class="header_search">Have a great day!</div>
        <div class="header_icon">header icon</div>
    </header>
    <aside class="sidenav"></aside>
    <main class="main">
        <div class="main-header">
            <div class="main-header__heading">Hello {{user.username}}</div>
            <div class="main-header__updates">Recent Items</div>
        </div>
        <div class="main-cards">
            <div class="card">Yearly Income {{ user.income }}</div>
            <div class="card">Net cash flow (monthly)</div>
            <div class="card">yearly outflow</div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="made_by">Made with care by Jay Donoghue</div>
    </footer>
</div>
```

query in python:

```
@app.route("/home")
@login_required
def home():
    user = users.query.filter(users._id == session["user_id"])
    db.session.commit()
    return render_template("home.html", user=user)
```

users table:

```
class users(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    _id = db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    username = db.Column("username", db.String(100))
    _hash = db.Column("hash", db.String(100))
    income = db.Column("income", db.Float)

    def __init__(self, username, _hash, income):
        self.username = username
        self._hash = _hash
        self.income = income

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.username}"
```

any help would be appreciated!